# Multisite domain not working without symlink

Tags: multi-sites, .htaccess

I used to have to work with my own custom `*.conf` file in order to get my multi-site to work off a non root install of drupal but now have moved it to root ,I don't need that file anymore as system reads the `.htaccess`.

So while my subdomains work fine in `sites` folder, my other domain name in `sites` folder refuses to work without symlink. Which I always thought was only necessary in tandem with `*.conf` file for *virtualDocument* hosts.

So my question is --

Why won't my other domain work like other sites in sites folder?

Why must it have a symlink to work?

And why do other sites have clean-urls working along with main install site but not other domain name?

My set up is

> mainsite.com/sites/
>
> ```
>                   subdomain.mainsite.com 
>                   subdomain2.mainsite.com
>                   otherdomain.com
> ```

If I symlink `otherdomain.com` while in `www` folder:

`ln -s /var/www/html/ /var/www/html/otherdomain.com`

It works but without clean-urls

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer now.

The symlink is necessary so two separate domains can share the one IP along with your server's records. Obviously the subdomains share the same name and so are fine just listed in sites directory. The symlink links the other domain or any number of domains to the same html folder where the root installation of drupal resides.

The clean urls for the symlink multi-site domain on my Centos 6.4 linux system running httpd require the default `httpd.conf` file in `etc/httpd/conf` to change `AllowOverride` NONE to All for directories. Then the service must be restarted for changes to take effect `service httpd restart`